# Power BI Filters Not Applying to All Visualizations

Tags: powerbi

How do I make filters apply to all visualizations? I am comparing 2 different power bi files that are exactly the same, but the filters apply to 1 file but not the other file for all visualizations.

Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding filtering on visuals, there are 3 type of filter available in Power BI as stated below-

1. **Report level filter:** Filter data set for whole report (all pages, all visuals).
2. **Page level filter:** Filter data for the specific page (all visuals in this page) where the filter implemented.
3. **Visual level filter:** Filter data for the specific visual only.

Now for your case, you need to check in which section you are applying the filter. Here below the filter configuration option available showing in the image.

[image]